# How to track site usage when Google Analytics is blocked?

Tags: google-analytics, usage-data, adblock

What are some good methods to track usage of your websites when Google Analytics numbers are just plain wrong?  I've found my internal logs don't match Google Analytics at all. I think ad blockers stop the analytics script from loading. So the site usage numbers are wildly different.

If it is important, my internal logs are only of users with accounts that actively log-in.

Update:

I have experimented a private tracker called Piwik.  By default it uses `Do Not Track` and doesn't log anyone with it enabled.  I can't find definitive information on Google Analytics, does anyone know if it is the same?

There are also articles on [how to track the number of Google Analytics blocks measured in GA](https://www.quantable.com/analytics/how-many-users-block-google-analytics/).

Comment: When you say *internal logs*, I assume outside of your web server logs. I like to recommend Piwik for web server log files. It is free and probably the best out there. I use Sawmill which has an expensive license and I will be switching to Piwik on the new server when I build it. It is that good! For what it is worth. Cheers!!

Comment: Yes, internal logs of sign-in times, screen resolution etc.

Comment: very most of adblocker have Google Analytics in their whitelists. If you have very different data in your logs and analytics, you should firstly audit your analytics setup in detail

Comment: While JavaScript based trackers may under-count visitors, server log tracking over-counts visitors because it will include bots.   Many bots masquerade as a browser by replicating the user-agent of a legitimate browser.   It is very difficult to do the tracking you want:  track 100% of legitimate visitors and no bots.